# Logging with winston: Is there a Cassandra transport?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, winston

Is there a [winston](https://github.com/dfoody/winston) transport for Cassandra?

I couldn't find any existing library, neither in the [documentation about transports](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md) nor with an `npm search winston`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've published a [Cassandra winston transport](https://github.com/jorgebay/winston-cassandra), you can get it via npm:

```
$ npm install winston-cassandra
```

It uses the [native Node.js driver for Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver), it targets any Cassandra version greater than or equal to 1.2.